# Python3 clip.duration of all mp4 files in a folder

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I am new to Python (using Python 3.6) and would like to extract the duration (in seconds) of all mp4 files I have in one folder. Code I have is:

```
path2 = path_directory
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path2):
        for filename in files:
            clip = VideoFileClip(files)
            print(clip.duration)
```

If I define `clip = VideoFileClip("name_of_one_specific_file.mp4")` it correctly prints the length (i.e. 590seconds) of that specific file, so I guess the mistake is in how I walk through all the files. I would need a list of the duration for each of the 245 mp4 files I have in path2.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `clip = VideoFileClip(filename)`?

Comment: Thank you Megalng. It worked for several "filenames" but it stops with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 283, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    line = [l for l in lines if keyword in l][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You just have a small error:

```
path2 = path_directory
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path2):
    for filename in files:
        clip = VideoFileClip(filename) # <= !!!
        print(clip.duration)
```

You want to open `filename`, not `files`. `filename` is the name of one specific file, `files` is the list of all files in a directory.

Comment: The programmer would also need to arrange to put path information into the call to `VideoFileClip`.

Comment: Thank you @Megalng. It worked for several "filenames" but it stops with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 283, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    line = [l for l in lines if keyword in l][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

There's a newer library, available from Python 3.4, that's generally easier to use than `walk`.  It's `pathlib`.

This is how you can use it in your situation.

```
from pathlib import Path
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

path2 = r' -------- '
for filename in Path(path2).glob('*.mp4'):
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename.as_posix())
    print(clip.duration)
```

Comment: Thank you @BillBell. As below, it iterates some files until I receive the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/path_to_my_python_code_file.py", line 333, in <module>
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename.as_posix())
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 81, in __init__
    fps_source=fps_source)
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.fps = infos['video_fps']
KeyError: 'video_fps'